# How to use CDN in vue cli?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, frontend, cdn

I am not familiar with packing frontend projects. When I was writing frontend, we just used JQuery. So the problem is now I have a project created by vue-cli and packed by webpack.

But as I don't want to load libraries from my local server but from remote CDN. How should I change the `yarn add` dependencies into CDN based form during `yarn build`? What is the correct way to do this kind of packing?

I've searched a lot but cannot find a good solution, some may suggest adding all CDN in the head section. But that's difficult to manage.

Comment: your generated package you need to serve (without a CDN) the Vue.js library dependency you can use from `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.0"></script>`

Comment: @Daniel That's a good idea, but here is a problem, how could I tell the webpack to not include the dependencies?

Comment: @Daniel I'm talking about using vue-cli. Which uses webpack as the build tool.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**1.** update your `public/index.html` adding the vue script source for the cdn (preferably in the head)

```html
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6"></script>
```

**2.** create a `vue.config.js` file in the project root with the following configuration.  (if you already have the file, add `configureWebpack` block to it)

```js
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    externals: {
      Vue: "vue"
    }
  }
};
```

this will flag the Vue dependency as a global, and not add it into the vendor bundle. You can do the same with other dependencies like `element-ui`, `vuetify`, `vuex`, etc...

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot and I will try it later.

Comment: It currently doesn't work and give `vue is not defined`. Btw, I am now using `yarn serve` to run a development server. Not sure if it matters.

Comment: sorry about that. it should be ` Vue: "vue"` not ` vue: "vue"` not sure why it worked like that when I tested it the first time, but I'm guessing I didn't clear the cache on the browser.

Comment: I also updated the src for vue. You may want to skip the patch version definition  to get the latest minor version. `2.6` will get the latest `2.6.*`, whereas having `2.6.0` will not have the (currently) last 10 patch releases